# How to use an external OpenShift namespace in cdi-camel

Tags: apache-camel, openshift, fabric8

I am trying to use the archetype cdi-camel-mq-archetype to test out an application running on OpenShift in its own namespace.  I want this application to use a message broker that is residing in a different namespace on the same OpenShift cluster.  But when I am running the application on OpenShift I see the following error in the POD's logs:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to process @Factory annotated method: create on bean: com.demo.mqdemotest.ActiveMQComponentFactory. Failed to lookup bean of type: class org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory for service: broker-tcp.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to process @Factory annotated method: create on bean: com.demo.mqdemotest.mq.ActiveMQConfigurer. Failed to lookup service broker-tcp.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No kubernetes service could be found for name: broker-tcp in namespace: null

Is there a way to inject the namespace that my broker lives in to my application (as I do not see a way to do this in the fabric8 cdi documentation)?  If not how could I get this to work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Depending on your setup:

- you can expose your service as a route and consume it in another project [OpenShift Origin: Routes](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/routes.html)
- you can join networks of the two projects [OpenShift Origin: Joining project networks](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/managing_pods.html#joining-project-networks)

In the future through linking support you will be able to directly provide a service from one project to another.

If you have a flat network in your OpenShift installation and no namespace segregation, the issue in your case might be how you reference your services between projects.

If you are in `camel-mq` project, you can use the services from `mq-demo` project using the url:

```
<service>.mq-demo.svc.cluster.local:<port>
```

To get services in your `mq-demo` run:

```
oc get svc -n mq-demo
```

More on networking can be found here: [OpenShift Origin: Networking](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/additional_concepts/networking.html)

Next possibility - based on the exception message `broker-tcp in namespace: null`. Maybe you should specify the namespace in which the `broker-tcp` service exists.

Comment: What does oc get netnamespaces return?

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me:

tcp://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port>